# Any function on a null set is measurable

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

in my Integration lectures there's this statement:

"If $m(E) = 0$, then any function $f$ on $E$ is measurable."

However I can't really see why this is true. My attempts so far:

Let $B(\mathbb{R})$ denote the Borel sigma algebra. We want to have that $\forall G \subset B(\mathbb{R})$, $ f^{-1}(G) $ would be measurable in order for $f$ to be measurable. I suspect that almost all of those preimages would be the empty set, hence there would be no problems but I can't prove it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: By definition $f^{-1}(G)\subseteq E$, since $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: All preimages $f^{-1}(G)$ of Borel sets $G$ will be subsets of $E$ by definition. If $m$ is a complete measure, then these preimages will be measurable since they are subsets of a null set $E$.

Comment: @jgon, apologies I wrote the question badly. And also, thank you both, I read the notes carefullly and this turns out to be an enforced condition in order to develop the Lebesgue integration